# Designing a publish and subscribe service (Callbacks vs Interface)

Tags: c#, oop, callback, publish-subscribe

Say I have need a service class that publishes data and subscribers can subscribe to data of interests.

How should I design the interface?
Is it bad design to pass callbacks? Doesn't feel OO to me

**Option 1**

```
public int Subscribe(string code, DataUpdatedDelegate callback) 
{
    this.subscribers[subscriptionId] = callback;
    this.codeSubscribers[code].Add(subscriptionId);
    ... 
    return subscriptionId;
}

public void UnSubscribe(int subscriptionId) 
{
    foreach list in codeSubscribers
        remove subscriptionId
    subscribers.remove(subscriptionId)
}

private void OnDataUpdated(int code, Data data)
{
     List<int> interestedSubscribers = codeSubscribers[code];
     foreach (int subId in interestedSubscribers)
     {
         DataUpdatedDelegate callback = this.subscribers[subId];
         callback(data);
     }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
public interface ISubscriber
{
    void ProcessData(Data data);
}

public int Register(ISubscriber subscriber)
{
    return subscriptionId;
}

public void Subscribe(string code, int subscriptionId) 
{
}

... rest similar to option 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic Observer pattern case, I would definitely go with option 2. Using an interface gives you more options. If later on you need to add more methods to the interface, you won't need to change much code.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with delegates, gives more freedom re message payloads, only the methods subscribe not the objects, and no messing with extend/interface/mixins/etc. They are the C# equivalent of what is used in Python for pypubsub (http://pypubsub.sourceforge.net) which works great.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, an interface is not supposed to change once it's released into the wild. Bear that in mind if you decide to use one.

Of course, the same could be said of a delegate's signature. Then again, you can always provide method overloads, and multiple delegate overloads (consider, for example, Action<T>, Action<T1, T2>, and so on).

Both techniques have their pros and cons; neither is a silver bullet. One that might lead you towards the interface-based approach is testability. It might be much easier to mock a callback if you had an interface to use. Then again, it might be just as easy with a delegate. If you're using a mocking framework, or dependency injection, however, interfaces are likely the way to go.